# How to use KKT to solve the problem with multiple sets of constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have two sets: $I=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $J=\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ and a set of subsets as $P=\{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_d\}$ that each member of $P$ is a subset of $I$, for example, $p_d=\{3,4\}$.
This is my optimization problem where $x_j$ is the decision variable and $z_{ij}$, $LC_i$, $T_{p_d}$, $U_j$ and $c_j$ are the parameters (constants) of the problem:

\begin{align}
&\min_{x_j} &\sum_{j \in J} c_j x_j \\
&\text{subject to:} & \sum_{j \in J}\frac{x_j z_{ij}}{x_j - U_j} &\leq LC_i && \forall i \in I\\ 
&&\sum_{i \in p_d}\sum_{j \in J}\frac{x_jz_{ij}}{x_j - U_j} &\leq T_{p_d} && \forall  p_d \in P \\ 
&& x_j &> U_j && \forall j \in J \\ 
&& x_j &\in \mathbb N 
\end{align}

If I relaxed the problem so that I consider $x_j$ as a continuous variable instead of integer, can I use KKT condition to solve this problem to find a closed form for $x_j$?

Comment: Are you sure the problem as stated here is complete? Because right now the variables $x_j$ seem to be completely independent (i.e. there is no constraint involving more than one $x_j$). Hence, you should be able to solve the problem for each variable separately.

Comment: @GraffL you are right, I should have added a sum over j in the constraints, I edited it.